# Custom transform '%' and '>' in numeric expressions in string columns, throughout a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apply

I've got several columns with '%' and '>' and I want to get rid of this and turn the columns into numbers. Here's how it looks like:

```
+----+-------------+--------+
|    | xRelegation | xChamp |
+----+-------------+--------+
| 11 | 12%         | <1%    |
| 12 | 20%         | <1%    |
| 13 | 27%         | <1%    |
| 14 | 85%         | <1%    |
| 15 | 91%         | <1%    |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

So I tried building this function so I could use on all columns that have these characters:

```
def get_prob(row):
    for i in df[row]:
        prob = 0
        i = i.replace('%','')
        if i == '<1':
            prob = 0.001
        elif i == '>99':
            prob = 99.99
        else:
            prob = pd.to_numeric(i)/100
    return prob
```

However, I tried computing this :

```
df.apply(get_prob("xChamp"), axis=1)
```

It did not work.

Comment: What specifically is the error or problem you are getting with the code you have already tried?

Comment: KeyError: 'xChamp'

Comment: `df.apply(get_prob("xChamp"), ...)` does not tell pandas to apply `get_prob` to `df['xChamp']` column. `get_prob("xChamp")` doesn't make syntactic sense. Also your function is supposed to take a row: `get_prob(row)`, it wouldn't make sense to pass in a column-name to the argument `row`?

Comment: Understood, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your fucntion `get_prob` does not need a loop for, more like:

```
def get_prob(row):
    if row == '<1%':
        return 0.001
    elif row == '>99%':
        return 99.99
    else:
        return pd.to_numeric(row.replace('%',''))/100
```

Then if you want to change your column, you use `apply` such as:

```
df['xRelegation'] = df['xRelegation'].apply(get_prob)
```

And same for the other column.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to loop over. For `df` as below:

```
  xChamp    xRelegation
0   <1%       12%
1   <1%       20%
```

The code using regex you can remove the characters that you want to remove from `df`,

```
import re
df = df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub('[<%$]', '', x)).astype(float)/100
df['xChamp'] = df['xChamp'].replace(dict(zip([0.01, 0.99],[0.001, 99.99])))
print(df)
```

Gives:

```
    xChamp  xRelegation
0   0.001   0.12
1   0.001   0.20
2   99.99   0.20
```

Have a look at [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for more information.

Comment: OP also wanted to transform '>99' to 99.99

Comment: @smci, thanks for spotting that. I also noticed for <1 OP wants to convert it to 0.001. I have added both the modifications now..

Answer (score 0):

use df.replace():

```
df.replace({'%':'','\<1':'0.001','\>99':'99.99'}, regex=True).astype(float)/100
```